# working with negative angle in a canvas game

Tags: math, game-physics, angle, pi, 360-degrees

I am making a top view medieval game using HTML, JS and canvas.

The problem is that my player is able to hit to others when not looking at them. I made a condition in the third line in the below code to address this problem, but that is not working because the player's look angle limits are max `180` and min `-180`. The limits between the player's position and victim's position are max `90` min `-270`. These limits ruin my condition.

I can accept any ideas or readymade condition or code.

```js
if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.X-Victim.X),2),Math.pow((this.Y-Victim.Y),2)) <= 100){//<-here calculates distance between victim and player
    var angle = Math.atan2(this.X - Victim.X , this.Y - Victim.Y) * (180 / Math.PI);//<-here calculates angle between victim and player
    if((angle < this.LookAngle + 45)&&(angle > this.LookAngle - 45)){//<- i need help on here
        console.log(angle,this.LookAngle);
        //socket.emit('HitTo',{UserName:Victim.UserName,hitval:20});//<- actually you dont need to know this
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `if(Math.abs(angle) < this.LookAngle + 45)` help? (Also, you don't need the Math.sqrt: use 10000, i.e. 100*100, instead of 100, and I'm pretty sure you should be adding those squared values, not putting a comma between them.)

Comment: i think i need math.sqrt because this not like 100*100 this like `hipotenus*hipotenus = a*a + b*b` @AndrewMorton

Comment: Square both sides: `sqrt(a*a + b*b) < x` => `a*a + b*b < x*x` and it saves the time to calculate sqrt. But that is only incidental to the problem.

Comment: yeah this not solves main problem XD

Comment: So, does `if(Math.abs(angle) < this.LookAngle + 45)` help? Ref: [Math.abs() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

Comment: Or if that isn't helping, one of the answers from Stack Overflow found by searching for "javascript check if two angles are close" should give you enough useful information to solve it.

Comment: i know i can use Math.abs to convert to positive but `-76 != 76` `-76 == 284` in degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering my own question

first i will flip my angle vertically because its must be reverse. [go to source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371844/10763408)

```js
180-angle
```

then i must convert the (look angle) and (angle between 2 player) to 0-360. [go to source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725005/10763408)

```js
(angle + 360) % 360
```

then i need to check the angle between in other two angle. [go to source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1044922)

```js
var isbetween = (startangle,midangle,endangle) => {
    endangle = (endangle- startangle) < 0 ? endangle - startangle + 360 : endangle - startangle;
    midangle = (midangle - startangle) < 0 ? midangle - startangle + 360 : midangle- startangle;
    return (midangle <  endangle); 
}
```

and applying to my code

```js
if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.X-Victim.X),2),Math.pow((this.Y-Victim.Y),2)) <= 100){
    var angle = Math.atan2(this.X - Victim.X , this.Y - Victim.Y) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var flippedangle = 180 - angle;
    var fixedangle = (flippedangle + 360) % 360;
    var fixedlook = (this.LookAngle + 360) % 360;
    if(((fixedangle - (fixedlook + 80)) < 0 ? fixedangle - (fixedlook + 80) + 360 : fixedangle - (fixedlook + 80)) > (((fixedlook - 80) - (fixedlook + 80)) < 0 ? (fixedlook - 80) - (fixedlook + 80) + 360 : (fixedlook - 80) - (fixedlook + 80))){
        socket.emit('HitTo',{UserName:Victim.UserName,hitval:20});
    }
}
```

Thank you

> Or if that isn't helping, one of the answers from Stack Overflow found by searching for "javascript check if two angles are close" should give you enough useful information to solve it. – Andrew Morton